# HBase Snapshot in Hive table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I have created a hbase table

```
create 'user_data_table','personal_data','professional_data';
```

Then I inserted few records into the table as

```
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:Location','IL'
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:FName','Deb'
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:LName','D'
put 'user_data_table','user1','professional_data:dept','IT'
put 'user_data_table','user1','professional_data:salary','2000'

put 'user_data_table','user2','personal_data:FName','CH'
put 'user_data_table','user2','personal_data:LName','AK'
put 'user_data_table','user2','professional_data:dept','IT'
put 'user_data_table','user2','professional_data:salary','80000'
```

I created a snapshot as `snapshot 'user_data_table', 'snapshot-day-1'`

Then I inserted/updated the record as below.

```
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:Location','VA'
put 'user_data_table','user1','professional_data:salary','3000'
```

When I try to refer the snapshot in my hive table, I am not getting the old data. Instead I am getting the latest data everytime. Any idea why its behaving like this. The command to create the hive table using hbase snapshot reference is as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table(key string, Location string,FName string,LName string, dept string,salary string) 
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:Location,personal_data:FName,personal_data:LName,professional_data:dept,professional_data:salary",
    "hive.hbase.snapshot.name"="snapshot-day-1")
    TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "user_data_table");
```

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot implies that (1) no information will be deleted from existing HFiles and (2) the content of these HFiles as-of-snapshot-creation can be *rebuilt on demand* (hiding whatever has been appended)

But [HIVE-6584](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6584) states that...

> Bypassing the online region server API provides a nice performance
>   boost for the full scan

...so maybe they chose to "bypass" the point-in-time-recovery part, and just used the snapshot as a backdoor for direct access to the HFiles. Including whatever has been appended since snapshot creation. Maybe.

Comment: Then in that case its similar to what is currently present in the table. Is there any place which can give a full insight on this ? I searched a lot but no where got any information.

Comment: When I try to recover the table from the snapshot, then its recovered and the old data is reverted back but when I try to refer the snapshot in hive table, then I dont get the old data.

Answer (score 0):

The DDL was wrong. The correct way to do so is as follows.

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists hbase_user_data_snapshot2_table(key string, Location string,FName string,LName string, dept string,salary string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:Location,personal_data:FName,personal_data:LName,professional_data:dept,professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hive.hbase.snapshot.name"="snapshot-day-2");
```

Note the TBLPROPERTIES. We dont refer the table instead refer the snapshot name.

Answer (score 0):

you need  set Hive Variables before select like this

```html
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists hbase_user_data_snapshot2_table(key string, Location string,FName string,LName string, dept string,salary string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:Location,personal_data:FName,personal_data:LName,professional_data:dept,professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hive.hbase.table.name"="xxx");

-- a table may be have many snapshot,so we configure it before select,
-- that is make sense
-- and if you snapshot file is store in a special path, please use 
-- SET hive.hbase.snapshot.restoredir= xxxx; to configure 
SET hive.hbase.snapshot.name=snapshot-day-2;
select * from hbase_user_data_snapshot2_table;
```